# Does verifying SAML signature depends on certificate

Tags: saml-2.0

If assertion party sends me signature with a public key and if they are using sha1 algorithm , does it mean that do I need to use same algorithm to verify the signature ?If this is the case , do we need to have sha1 certificate as well ?

Answer (score 1):

No, the algorithm of the certificate is used to ensure the validity of the certificate. That is an entirely different algorithm than the hash used for the Xml Signature.

If the Xml signature is created with a SHA-2 algorithm, you will have to use SHA-2 when you verify the signature. Xml Dsig libraries typically handles this automatically.

That said, using SHA1 signatures is not recommended for any usage any more so the Idp creating the assertion should use SHA2 or better when signing.

Comment: Able, thanks for the reply .Sorry as I need much more detail to understand this. Lets say customer has sent me signature using SHA2 alogorithm . I have got couple of questions how customer signs it -- : 1) When customer signs it, do they use their private key using SHA2 algorithm and in order to verify that , I need to use their public key using SHA2 algorithm ? OR 2) When customer signs it, do they use our public key using SHA2 algorithm and in order to verify that , I need to use our private key using SHA2 algorithm ?

Comment: Does anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more details with regard to your original question. For the questions on what key to use - that's a different question. Please post as a new question as the Stack Overflow format doesn't handle follow-up questions as comments very well.